# issue running rake test chapter 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake-test

I am trying to run the rake test on the sample app and I have 1 error that I cannot seem to shift.

```
`ERROR["test_invalid_signup_information", UsersSignupTest, 0.717775303]     test_invalid_signup_information#UsersSignupTest (0.72s)ArgumentError:         ArgumentError: unknown     command 'v'            test/integration/users_signup_test.rb:15:in `test'                test/integration/users_signup_test.rb:15:in `block in <class:UsersSignupTest>'            test/integration/users_signup_test.rb:15:in `test'        test/integration/users_signup_test.rb:15:in     `block in <class:UsersSignupTest>'
  16/16: [=] 100% Time: 00:00:00, Time: 00:00:00

Finished in 0.72207s
16 tests, 34 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips1
```

it seems to point to the users_signup page which I have pasted below.

```
`require 'test_helper'

class UsersSignupTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  test "invalid signup information" do
    get signup_path
    assert_no_difference 'User.count' do
      post users_path, user: { name:  "",
                               email: "user@invalid",
                               password:              "foo",
                               password_confirmation: "bar" }
    end
    assert_template 'users/new'

  test "valid signup information" do
    get signup_path
    name     = "Example User"
    email    = "user@example.com"
    password = "password"
    assert_difference 'User.count', 1 do
      post_via_redirect users_path, user: { name:  name,
                                            email: email,
                                            password:              password,
                                            password_confirmation: password }
    end
    assert_template 'users/show'
    end
  end
end
```

can anyone see the error?

Comment: There looks a missing `end` in first test and also is there a false `"`"` next to require (first line) ?

Comment: Have added the extra 'end' tag and now the test fails as there are too many end tags.

Comment: I was having a similar issue, but it was because I had done a `post` and not a `post_via_redirect`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps because you didn't close the control flow structure of the first test ? There's an `end` missing.

Try with the code like this:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersSignupTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  test "invalid signup information" do
    get signup_path
    assert_no_difference 'User.count' do
      post users_path, user: { name:  "",
                               email: "user@invalid",
                               password:              "foo",
                               password_confirmation: "bar" }
    end
    assert_template 'users/new'
  end

  test "valid signup information" do
    get signup_path
    name     = "Example User"
    email    = "user@example.com"
    password = "password"
    assert_difference 'User.count', 1 do
      post_via_redirect users_path, user: { name:  name,
                                            email: email,
                                            password:              password,
                                            password_confirmation: password }
    end
    assert_template 'users/show'
  end
end
```

Comment: Have added the extra 'end' tag and now the test fails as there are too many end tags